# pivot csv file rows into columns and save in file

Tags: python, csv, pivot

I have multiple CSV files at a folder. I have to read columnheader and first 2 rows of each file and write the output in a csv file in format rows into columns.

Example - FileName: Test1.csv

```
ID   ProductName
1    ABC
2    AA
3    CC
10  Q
11  s
```

FileName: Test2.csv

```
Code Description
A    AAAA
B    BBBB
C    CCCC
D    DDDD
```

Required Outfile format - Outputfile.csv

```
FileName    Column          Row1  Row2
Test1.csv   Id               1     2
Test1.csv   ProductName     ABC    AA
Test2.csv   Code             A     B
Test2.csv   Description     AAAA   BBBB
```

The code is:

```
with open(full_file_path,'r') as f_input:
                try:
                    columninfo = f_input.readline()
                    row_1 = next(f_input)
                    row_2 = next(f_input)

                    filedata = columninfo +';'+ row_1 +';'+ row_2
                    output = file +';'+ moddate +';'+ str(file_size) +';'+ file_delim +';'+ filedata
                    outputfinal = full_file_path +';'+ output + '\n'

                    ofile.write(outputfinal)
                    f_input.close()
                except:
                    pass
```

Comment: What result have you got with the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should work. It uses `;` as the output delimiter and uses the `csv.Sniffer` to automatically determine the delimiter being used for each of the source files:

```
from datetime import datetime
import itertools
import csv
import sys
import os


script, path, output = sys.argv

with open(output, 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output, delimiter=';')
    csv_output.writerow(['FolderFilePath', 'FileName', 'ModifiedDate', 'FileSize', 'Delimiter', 'Columns'])

    for root, folders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)
            file_size = os.path.getsize(full_file_path)
            mod_date = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(full_file_path)).strftime('%Y %m %d')
            start_cols = [full_file_path, file, mod_date, file_size]

            with open(full_file_path, 'rb') as f_csv:
                try:
                    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f_csv.read(1024))
                    start_cols.append(dialect.delimiter)
                    f_csv.seek(0)
                    csv_input = csv.reader(f_csv, dialect)

                    for row in itertools.izip(*itertools.islice(csv_input, 3)):
                        csv_output.writerow(start_cols + list(row))
                except csv.Error:
                    csv_output.writerow(start_cols + ["Unknown delimiter"])
```

This will give you the following output CSV file:

```
FolderFilePath;FileName;ModifiedDate;FileSize;Delimiter;Columns
c:\My Folder\Test1.csv;Test1.csv;2017 01 09;45;,;ID;1;2
c:\My Folder\Test1.csv;Test1.csv;2017 01 09;45;,;ProductName;ABC;AA
c:\My Folder\Test2.csv;Test2.csv;2017 01 09;48;,;Code;A;B
c:\My Folder\Test2.csv;Test2.csv;2017 01 09;48;,;Description;AAAA;BBBB
```

Python's `csv` module is used to convert a Python list automatically into a CSV row. It adds all the necessary delimiters for you. If any of the entries contain the delimiter, it also automatically adds quotes around it.

Comment: Hi Martin, Many thanks for your help. Maybe I missed something but I am getting the error: IndexError: list index out of range for the 2nd row. If I only read 1 row, then it works fine.

Comment: It currently assumes all of your input files contain two columns, if this is not the case could you give an example. Can you also confirm exactly the CSV format, i.e. is it commas, tabs, spaces?

Comment: Hi Martin, number of columns are different in each file. i.e. first file can have columns Id, Name , Location. 2nd file can have Code and Description. Its commas separated.

Comment: Try now, I've modified it to work with a variable number of columns.

Comment: Many thanks Martin, its working perfectly fine. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Hi Martin, If I am reading multiple files (.csv, .txt etc) then is there any way to get the delimiter being used in each file and store in the output file along with other details as mentioned in your script.

Comment: Thanks Martin, can you please look at this code posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41587578/read-file-headers-and-delimiters-using-python

Comment: [`csv.sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.sniffer#csv.Sniffer) will do this. Alternatively you you could try reading in the header from each file using a list of different delimiters and decide which gives you the most entries.

Comment: Hi Martin, Can you please review the attached code - its not concatenating columninfo with row data in single lines. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Where is the attached code?  If you are having a problem with the script, perhaps you could post a link to the CSV file causing the problem. Take a look at [0bin](https://0bin.net/), it lets you upload files and post links to them (don't use the short link feature though - it sometimes doesn't work)

Comment: Hi Martin, here is the code - https://0bin.net/paste/RsyMGI3JEjz7-hOi#EwYpcuC4VAYfp94fjUiHqzdfZ2YbEzflraE3fz7nmoT

Comment: Issue in the code is in last part for row2 and row3 data - row 2 and row3 data are coming in same line along with column info etc. its coming in next line in csv output file. Last week I worked on this code and used similar logic which was working fine; somehow deleted that file so trying to understand what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: You really should use Python's `csv`. It takes a list and automatically adds the necessary delimiters in between each entry for you. Without it you must split each of your rows yourself using the delimiter when reading in. Without csv [your code](https://0bin.net/paste/xq4lDK7S+sVRwVEn#qoWkYFi2HhiwfWuZeMKkx7TsdWJZVXW5tJTXOxmxCmR) becomes very poor quality.

Comment: Hi Martin, but I have to read all kind of files not only csv, will it work ? Also this code will it work even if there are less than 2 rows in the files ?