# Read File headers and delimiters using Python

Tags: python, csv, delimiter

I am reading all the files from a given folder (contains Dir, Sub dir and files of type .csv, .txt ..)

I need to get the following information into an output file in the following format:

```
FileLocation, FileName, Delimiter, Columns
```

(All columns needed in a cell separated by delimiter)

I am using the following script which works fine except delimiter. I have tried using csv.sniffer but it does not work.

```
import sys,os,csv

ofilew = open('D:\OutputFile/Columns_Info.csv', 'w')
ofile = open('D:\OutputFile/Columns_Info.csv', 'a')

root = 'D:\UnZipFiles'
path = os.path.join(root)

columninfo = 'FolderLocation, FileName, Delimiter, Columns' + '\n'
ofilew.write(columninfo)

for r,d,f in os.walk(path):
    for file in f:
        fullfilepath = os.path.join(r,file)
        with open(fullfilepath,'r') as f:
            columninfo = f.readline()
            columninfo = columninfo.replace(",", ";")

            output = file +','+ columninfo
            outputfinal = r + ',' + output

            ofile.write(outputfinal)
```

Comment: Please add more detail about what exactly does not work.

Comment: yes, `csv.sniffer` is certainly the best tool to use here. What did not work with csv.sniffer?

Comment: Please add an example of file that fails to work with `csv.sniffer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following approach should work for you, it uses Python's [`csv.sniffer`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.sniffer#csv.Sniffer) feature to attempt to determine the correct dialect to use for reading the file. This also contains the delimiter that is used.

```
import os, csv

header_output = ['FolderLocation', 'FileName', 'Delimiter', 'Columns']
path = r'D:\UnZipFiles'

with open(r'D:\OutputFile\Columns_Info.csv', 'wb') as f_output:
    csv_output = csv.writer(f_output)
    csv_output.writerow(header_output)

    for root, folders, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            full_file_path = os.path.join(root, file)

            with open(full_file_path, 'rb') as f_input:
                try:
                    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f_input.read(1024))
                    f_input.seek(0)
                    csv_input = csv.reader(f_input, dialect)
                    header_input = next(csv_input)
                    csv_output.writerow([root, file, dialect.delimiter] + header_input)
                except csv.Error as e:
                    print "{} - could not determine the delimiter".format(file)
```

As an alternative to `csv.sniffer`, you could devise your own, but the Python one is much more powerful than this:

```
def get_delimiter(file_name):            
    cols_found = []

    for delim in [',', ';', '|', '\t']:
        with open(file_name, 'rb') as f_in:
            cols_found.append([len(next(csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=delim))), delim])

    if cols_found[-1][0] > 1:
        return sorted(cols_found)[-1][1]
    else:
        return None


print get_delimiter('my.csv')
```

This returns a possible delimiter by counting which delimiter results in the most columns in the first row. If only one column is found, it returns `None` to indicate no matching delimiter was found. It could instead raise an exception.

Comment: Hi Martin,  The function get_delimiter - is it possible to make it generic for files like .csv or .dat or .txt ?  I mean if it can read all type of files and get the delimiter used in the file.

Comment: You can try and pass any file to it, e.g. `my.txt`. You might find that some files fail to parse. I have modified it to return `None` if only 1 column is detected for all attempts to match.